# Implementation of Bluetooth HID device profile in Android Kitkat

Tags: android, bluetooth, hid

I want to implement Bluetooth HID device role in An android based system.It has KitKat in it.. By default Android Kitkat has support for HID Host role... But I am unable to get an idea about how to implement the device role..

I have seen this video link
http://hsc.com/Blog/Android-Labs-Bluetooth-HID-device-implementation-your-phone-as-a-mouse-voice-control

here they said that they had changed a little in framework and classic Bluetooth application ...they had also used one flag....

I am new to Android environment. Can anyone help me...???

Answer (score 0):

You have to change Bluetooth stack and build a customized ROM. The work is not simple.